# Having Troubles With This Integration Problem

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The question I'm having troubles with is as follows:

Evaluate $\int_{-r}^r\sqrt{r^2-t^2}\,dt$ 
(Hint: substitute $t=r\sin x$)

So, immediately I did $dt=r\cos x\,dx$ and substitute it all in...

$\int r\cos x\sqrt{r^2-r^2\sin^2 x}\,dx$

And here's where I'm having a problem: I'm not sure what the new boundaries would be, if there is a new boundary. My thinking is that the new boundaries for both would be $r\sin (r)$ which then would make the answer zero but I feel as if that would be wrong (and quite frankly too easy).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One can also evaluate this integral by identifying a familiar shape whose area it represents. (If the purpose of this computation is to derive the formula for that shape by integration, this argument is of course circular.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$r^2-r^2\sin^2x = r^2(1-\sin^2x) = r^2\cos^2x$, and the new limits are $-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, and $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$. To see this you solve: $-r = r\sin x \Rightarrow \sin x = - 1\Rightarrow x = -\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, and the same for the upper limit.

Comment: I know that. That part isn't the issue. It's the boundaries I'm having difficulties in.

Comment: Ooops, never mind.

Comment: Though, how did you get the boundaries, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: boundary = limit?